# Сделать ссылку кликабельной

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать преобразователь вставленных урлов в кликабельные ссылки, причём даже без http://. Выходит что попало, так как не дружу с регулярками, вот код:

```
$text = 'Тестик test.ru http://test.ru';
$text = preg_replace('`(http(?:s)?://\w+[^\s\[\]\<]+)`i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
$text= preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(ru|com|net)/i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: "*Выходит что попало*"  - и будет, потому как нет на 100% надёжного способа отличить ссылку от нессылки, если она не начитается с протокола. Попробуйте для начала сузить критерии и сформулировать чёткие правила что считать ссылкой, а что нет. На словах, а не в регекспе.

Comment: @PinkTux для чего по вашему перечисляю домены? ru|com|net

Comment: Не знаю, потому как вторым регекспом вы полностью убиваете результаты работы первого, и логика этого действия мне не понятна.

Comment: @Rammsteinik, и `target="_blank"` лучше вообще ни где не используйте. Это уязвимость для вашего сайта ;)

Comment: @Visman,` target="_blank"` в чём тут уязвимость?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, https://habrahabr.ru/post/282880/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$text = 'Тестик 1.test.ru 2.<a href="http://www.test.ru">test.ru ok</a> 3.https://test.ru';
$patt = array(
    '%\b(?<!href=[\'"])https?://([^\s\[\]<]+)(?![^<>]*</a>)%i',
    '%\b(?<!http://)(?<!https://)[a-z\d]+\.(ru|com|net)(?!["\'][^<>]*>)(?![^<>]*</a>)%i'
);
$repl = array(
    '<a href="$0">$1</a>',
    '<a href="http://$0">$0</a>'
);
$text = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $text);
echo $text;
```

Здесь:

`\b` - граница слова, тут нужна для захвата всего слова (например `test`), а не его части (`est`);

`(?<!href=[\'"])` - исключает захват ссылки из тега **A** (например от сюда `<a href="http://test.ru">`);

`(?<!http://)(?<!https://)` - исключает захват ссылок из обработанных первой регуляркой;

`(?![^<>]*</a>)` - исключает захват ссылки из тега **A** (например от сюда `test.ru ok</a>`);

`(?!["\'][^<>]*>)` - исключает захват ссылки из тега **A** (например от сюда `<a href="http://www.test.ru">`).

**P.S.** Данное решение все равно не учитывает всех нюансов ;)

**UPD** Вариант с более сложными регулярками, приближенными к [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)

```
$text = 'Тестик 1. abc.test.ru 2. <a href="http://www.test.ru">http://test.ru ok</a> 3. https://test.ru/search?search_id=975080714';
$patt = array(
    '%\b(?<!href=[\'"])(?>https?://|www\.)([\p{L}\p{N}]+[\p{L}\p{N}\-]*\.(?:[\p{L}\p{N}\-]+\.)*[\p{L}\p{N}]{2,})(?::\d+)?(?:(?:(?:/[\p{L}\p{N}$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),\%;:@&=-]+)+|/)(?:\?[\p{L}\p{N}$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),\%;:@&=-]+)?(?:#[^\s\<\>]+)?)?(?![^<]*+</a>)%u',
    '%\b(?<!http://)(?<!https://)([\p{L}\p{N}]+[\p{L}\p{N}\-]*\.(?:[\p{L}\p{N}\-]+\.)*(?:ru|com|net))(?::\d+)?(?:(?:(?:/[\p{L}\p{N}$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),\%;:@&=-]+)+|/)(?:\?[\p{L}\p{N}$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),\%;:@&=-]+)?(?:#[^\s\<\>]+)?|\b)(?![^<]*+</a>)%u'
);
$repl = array(
    '<a href="$0">$1</a>',
    '<a href="http://$0">$1</a>'
);
$text = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите, как решить проблему с поддоменами, `zxc.test.ru` видит как `zxc.<a href="http://test.ru">test.ru</a>`

Comment: @Rammsteinik, `[a-z\d]+` во второй регулярке можно попробовать заменить на `(?:[a-z\d]+(?:[a-z\d\.]*[a-z\d])?)`.