# Правильное регулярное выражение на "Кикабельные ссылки"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Прошу помочь с составлением регулярного выражения для определения и замены сылок в тексте на  html код вида

```
<a href="ссылка">ссылка</a>
```

на голову приходит что то вроде этого:

```
$text = preg_replace('`(http(?:s)?://\w+[^\s\[\]\<]+)`i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
$text= preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9].([ru])([net])([com])/i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
```

но оно не будет распознавать некоторые ссылки, да и думаю не совсем верно составлено, хотелось бы чтобы чтобы оно поддерживало ссылки вида

1. www.название.любаядоменнаязона
2. название.любаядоменнаязона
3. [http://название.любаядоменнаязона](http://%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)
4. [https://название.любаядоменнаязона](https://%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)
5. и так же с под доменами
6. и др

тут ещё не знаю какой самый длинный домен может быть? просто не хотелось бы видеть что-то подобное на: `ывапьвпьваьпьвапьвапьваьппвапвапвпавпвапвапвапвапавпвапвапвапвапвапвапав.ru`

Comment: самый длинный домен - не более 64 символов между точками, вот пример http://www.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com/

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542842/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9/543079#543079 я давал ответ, но p.s. читайте.

Comment: "*на голову приходит что то вроде этого*" - интересно, почему одна и та же хренотень регулярно приходит на голову разным юзерам SO-RU?

Comment: Я уже поднимал эту тему и похоже что то человек скопировал из моего вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/492097/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: @RedWoolf, дополнил тот ответ по ссылке из моего коммента.