# JEditorPane обертка ссылки в теги

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, ссылки, текст, теги

Всем привет!

Есть JEditorPane, в который может записываться текст вида:

> Lorem ipsum http://google.com Lorem https://anotherlink ipsum

Задача: приделать всем ссылкам тег `<a>` или другим способ сделать их кликабельными.

Пробовал делать так, но цикл получается бесконечный :

```
String texx = data.getText();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*((http://|https://)\\S+\\.\\S+).*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(texx);
while(m.matches()){
    texx.replace(m.group(2), "<a href='"+m.group(2)+"'&gt;" + m.group(2) + "a&gt;");
    System.out.println(texx);
    m = p.matcher(texx);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m.matches()` проверяет всю строку на совпадение с регулярным выражением, а она каждый раз будет совпадать, поскольку `.*` в начале и в конце, а сама ссылка не меняется. Можно просто использовать `String.replaceAll`:

```
String texx = "Lorem ipsum http://google.com Lorem https://anotherlink.site ipsum";

texx = texx.replaceAll( "((?:http|https)\\S+\\.\\S+)", "<a>$1</a>" );
System.out.println( texx ); //Lorem ipsum <a>http://google.com</a> Lorem <a>https://anotherlink.site</a> ipsum
```

Вместо `$1` в строку замены будет поставлен текст, захваченный первой группой. Протокол завернут в `(?: )` - незахватывающую (noncapturing) группу.

Вообще выделение url регуляркой в тексте - нетривиальная задача, примеры более сложных регулярок:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543079/190934
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/5661663

возможно, следует поискать библиотечное решение.