# Регулярка для url под любые языки мира

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.
На сайте использовалась регулярка для url вида http://domen.com/themename/pagename.html

Для pagename использовалась регулярка вида 
([a-z0-9\-/]+)
т.е. предполагалось что pagename будет состоять из английских букв, цифр, тире, может быть слэш.
Однако теперь необходимо её переписать с допущением, что pagename может быть на любом языке мира - английском, русском, французком, испанском и т.д. Подскажите как лучше всего составить регулярное выражение.
Версия PHP на сервере 5.6.24

Comment: Не знаю, как в ПХП, а вообще [вот тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D1.8B_URI) приводится регулярка для разбора URI на части.

Comment: А что это выражение должно делать? Находить ссылки в более длинном тексте? Что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542842/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9/543079#543079 В первой регулярке удалите `(?<!href=[\'"])` и `(?![^<]*+</a>)` и получите нужную регулярку

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша регулярка вас не устраивает только тем что не поддерживает языки, тогда вот эта вам подойдет `([\pL_0-9\-/]+)`