# Найти все ссылки в тексте, исключая тег <a>

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер!
Есть регулярка для определения ссылок в тексте:

`preg_match_all('/(https?:\/\/)?([\w\.\-\_]+)\.(com|net|org|edu|gov|biz|info|name|ru|ua|рф|[a-z]{2,6}\.?)(\/[\w\.\&\?\=\-\_\:]*)*\/?/', $text, $externalURLs);`

Как мне исключить ссылки, которые находятся в теге `<a[href]>` одним регулярным выражением?

Добавляю `(?!href="([^"]+))` - не хочет работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать ссылку кликабельной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542842/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берём регулярку из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988

```
/(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gi
```

и выкидываем те, которые в href

```
(?<!href\s*=\s*["'],)
```

Получается так:

```
/(?<!href\s*=\s*["']?)(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gi
```

Comment: Сработал только такой код: `/(?<!href=[\"'])(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/i` с `\s*` - почему-то ошибку выдавало

Comment: Но данное выражение берет еще и теги в конце (напр. <li>www.google.com</li> ссылка будет www.google.com</li>). Как это можно устранить?

Answer (score 0):

Для понимания использования конструкций вида `(?<!...)` и `(?!...)` я написал шаблон с использованием модификатора **x**. Благодаря этому стало возможным  расставить комментарии внутри regex-шаблонов. В этом примере будут найдены две ссылки :

1. httрs://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988
2. httрs://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988

Ссылка внутри html-тега будет проигнорирована.

**Примечание:** символ **^** в комментариях ниже указывает на совпавшую позицию в тексте

Коммент. №1: негативная ретроспективная проверка. Совпадает с ПОЗИЦИЕЙ в тексте, слева от которой отсутствует подстрока href="**^**

Коммент. №2: ищет вхождения url-адресов, которые могут начинаться с протоколов http или https, за которыми обязательно следуют символы :// после которых следуют любые символы, кроме пробела. Пробел означает конец url-адреса *(url-адреса не содержат пробелов)*.

Коммент. №3: негативная опережающая проверка. Совпадает с ПОЗИЦИЕЙ в тексте, справа от которой отсутствует подстрока **^**">

```
$text = 'Будут найдены две ссылки : 
1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988 
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988 
А ссылка внутри html-тега будет проигнорирована : 
<a href="http://htmlbook.ru/example/knob.html">Ссылка</a>';

$patt = '~
    (?<!href=")      # Коммент. №1
        https?://\S+ # Коммент. №2
    (?!">)           # Коммент. №3
~x';

preg_match_all($patt, $text, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

[Демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3632127b7a8c2c270ec5ab80108d8fb810327bc8)

Answer (score -1):

```
$patt = '~
    (?<!href=")      # Коммент. №1
        https?://[^\s<&]+ # Коммент. №2
    (?!">)           # Коммент. №3
~x';
```

Т.к. после ссылки сразу может идти не пробел, а тэг или & , например &ndsp;